# jQuery calendar opening and closing times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have attached a calendar and opening on my site but it doesn't seem to be working don't know why here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            switch(curday){
                case 0:
                    day = "sunday";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    day = "<h2>Monday</h2><br/>9:00-12:00 <br/> 12:00-13:00 Lunch<br/> 13:00-19:00<br/>";
                    break;
            case 2:
                    day = "Tuesday";
                    break;
            case 3:
                    day = "<h2>Wednesday</h2><br/>9:00-12:00 <br/> 12:00-13:00 Lunch<br/> 13:00-19:00<br/>";
                    break;
            case 4:
                    day = "Thursday";
                    break;
            case 5:
                    day = "<h2>Friday</h2><br/>9:00-12:00 <br/> 12:00-13:00 Lunch<br/> 13:00-19:00<br/>";
                    break;
            case 6:
                    day = "Saturday" "We are closed" ;
                    break;
            }
            document.write(day);

</script>
```

and this is code for the calender

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var todaydate=new Date()
        var curmonth=todaydate.getMonth()+1 //get current month (1-12)
        var curyear=todaydate.getFullYear() //get current year

        document.write(buildCal(curmonth ,curyear, "main", "month", "daysofweek", "days", 1));
</script>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how do i get the day to show in the browser and the day the store is closed.